# Does it make sense to use queue-depth when doing synchronous IO benchmark?

Tags: ssd, benchmark, fio

Does it make sense to have a queue depth > 1 when doing a synchronous IO benchmark?

I was expecting the same result a of QD1, but QD32 does give better result?

I thought it would just be ignored. In the fio [manual](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-iodepth) for the option `--iodepth`:

> Note that increasing iodepth beyond 1 will not affect synchronous ioengines...

fio commands:

```
fio --name=x --ioengine=posixaio --rw=write --bs=4k --iodepth=1 --size=512MB --fsync=1  --filename=test.img 
Result:  5.210 IOPS / 20MB/s

fio --name=x --ioengine=posixaio --rw=write --bs=4k --iodepth=32 --size=512MB --fsync=1  --filename=test.img 
Result: 20.100 IOPS /  79MB/s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(The following is in reference to [fio](https://github.com/axboe/fio))

> Does it make sense to have a queue depth > 1 when doing a synchronous IO benchmark?

No (this is a simplification but you can read the [fio documentation for the special cases](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-iodepth)).

> I though[t] it would just be ignored.
>
> > Note that increasing iodepth beyond 1 will not affect synchronous ioengines...
>
> [example of showing iodepth having an impact on `posixaio` ioengine]

`posixaio` is an **a**synchronous ioengine ([aio = asynchronous I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) :-) If you look at https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/fio-3.23/engines/posixaio.c#L246 you will notice it doesn't set the `FIO_SYNCIO` flag (see https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/fio-3.23/ioengines.h#L65 for where the flag is defined).

When you use an async ioengine with an `iodepth` > 1 you are by definition trying to create an asynchronous I/O benchmark. You can (somewhat) simulate synchronous behaviour with an async ioengine by using an `iodepth` of 1 but you will pay some (likely small) overhead for using a redundant asynchrony mechanism. Alternatively, you can use a purely sync I/O engine instead ([look for ioengines with sync in their name](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-ioengine)) and you should find that `iodepth` doesn't impact your results with them (because they are truly synchronous!).

Comment: So I need to change ioengine for synchronous benchmark?....what would be the best choice for general synchronous IO test....`sg`?

Comment: You kinda of have two options: use a sync [ioengine](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_man.html#cmdoption-arg-ioengine) (like pvsync2) or use an async ioengine with a depth of 1 (slightly less efficient but if you're not going for crazy high speeds... although [posixaio is not the fastest of fio's ioengines on Linux](https://github.com/axboe/fio/issues/718#issuecomment-441529946)). Also be aware [`sg` is a specialist ioengine](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_man.html#cmdoption-arg-ioengine) with limitations of its own - you aren't going to be able to use it on regular files...